# How to get VS2008 to use __cdecl rather than __thiscall in C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, linker

I am trying to build an open source C++ project in Visual Studio 2008. I load the solution file and everything compiles, but I'm getting a bunch of linking errors due to certain methods not being found. After using DUMPBIN.EXE to examine the .lib file in question, I can see what the problem is: the methods in the .lib all have `__cdecl` in their signatures, while the linker is looking for the equivalent methods with `__thiscall` instead.

How can I get VS 2008 to use `__cdecl` instead?

NOTE: The project is [a fork of CCV](https://github.com/pwjones/ccv_pgr), a multi-touch tracking program based on OpenCV. The purpose of this fork is to provide support for a camera called the Flea3 via the FlyCapture2 libraries provided by the camera's maker. Here are the linker errors:

```
1>ofxFlea3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall FlyCapture2::Image::Image(void)" (__imp_??0Image@FlyCapture2@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall ofxFlea3::ofxFlea3(void)" (??0ofxFlea3@@QAE@XZ)
1>ofxFlea3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall FlyCapture2::Image::~Image(void)" (__imp_??1Image@FlyCapture2@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall ofxFlea3::ofxFlea3(void)" (??0ofxFlea3@@QAE@XZ)
1>ofxFlea3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall FlyCapture2::Camera::Camera(void)" (__imp_??0Camera@FlyCapture2@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall ofxFlea3::ofxFlea3(void)" (??0ofxFlea3@@QAE@XZ)
1>ofxFlea3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall FlyCapture2::Camera::~Camera(void)" (__imp_??1Camera@FlyCapture2@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall ofxFlea3::ofxFlea3(void)" (??0ofxFlea3@@QAE@XZ)
1>ofxFlea3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall FlyCapture2::Error::~Error(void)" (__imp_??1Error@FlyCapture2@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl PrintError(class FlyCapture2::Error)" (?PrintError@@YAXVError@FlyCapture2@@@Z)
1>ofxFlea3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void __thiscall FlyCapture2::Error::PrintErrorTrace(void)const " (__imp_?PrintErrorTrace@Error@FlyCapture2@@UBEXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl PrintError(class FlyCapture2::Error)" (?PrintError@@YAXVError@FlyCapture2@@@Z)
1>ofxFlea3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual class FlyCapture2::Error __thiscall FlyCapture2::BusManager::GetCameraFromIndex(unsigned int,class FlyCapture2::PGRGuid *)" (__imp_?GetCameraFromIndex@BusManager@FlyCapture2@@UAE?AVError@2@IPAVPGRGuid@2@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall ofxFlea3::listDevices(void)" (?listDevices@ofxFlea3@@QAEXXZ)
1>ofxFlea3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall FlyCapture2::BusManager::~BusManager(void)" (__imp_??1BusManager@FlyCapture2@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall ofxFlea3::listDevices(void)" (?listDevices@ofxFlea3@@QAEXXZ)
1>ofxFlea3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall FlyCapture2::Error::Error(class FlyCapture2::Error const &)" (__imp_??0Error@FlyCapture2@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall ofxFlea3::listDevices(void)" (?listDevices@ofxFlea3@@QAEXXZ)
1>ofxFlea3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual class FlyCapture2::Error __thiscall FlyCapture2::BusManager::GetNumOfCameras(unsigned int *)" (__imp_?GetNumOfCameras@BusManager@FlyCapture2@@UAE?AVError@2@PAI@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall ofxFlea3::listDevices(void)" (?listDevices@ofxFlea3@@QAEXXZ)
1>ofxFlea3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall FlyCapture2::Error::Error(void)" (__imp_??0Error@FlyCapture2@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall ofxFlea3::listDevices(void)" (?listDevices@ofxFlea3@@QAEXXZ)
1>ofxFlea3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall FlyCapture2::BusManager::BusManager(void)" (__imp_??0BusManager@FlyCapture2@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall ofxFlea3::listDevices(void)" (?listDevices@ofxFlea3@@QAEXXZ)
1>ofxFlea3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual class FlyCapture2::Error __thiscall FlyCapture2::Image::Save(char const *,enum FlyCapture2::ImageFileFormat)" (__imp_?Save@Image@FlyCapture2@@UAE?AVError@2@PBDW4ImageFileFormat@2@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall ofxFlea3::initFlea3(int,int,int,int)" (?initFlea3@ofxFlea3@@QAEXHHHH@Z)
1>ofxFlea3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual class FlyCapture2::Error __thiscall FlyCapture2::Image::Convert(enum FlyCapture2::PixelFormat,class FlyCapture2::Image *)const " (__imp_?Convert@Image@FlyCapture2@@UBE?AVError@2@W4PixelFormat@2@PAV12@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall ofxFlea3::initFlea3(int,int,int,int)" (?initFlea3@ofxFlea3@@QAEXHHHH@Z)
1>ofxFlea3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual class FlyCapture2::Error __thiscall FlyCapture2::Image::ReleaseBuffer(void)" (__imp_?ReleaseBuffer@Image@FlyCapture2@@UAE?AVError@2@XZ) referenced in function "protected: virtual void __thiscall ofxFlea3::getNewFrame(unsigned char *)" (?getNewFrame@ofxFlea3@@MAEXPAE@Z)
1>ofxFlea3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual struct FlyCapture2::TimeStamp __thiscall FlyCapture2::Image::GetTimeStamp(void)const " (__imp_?GetTimeStamp@Image@FlyCapture2@@UBE?AUTimeStamp@2@XZ) referenced in function "protected: virtual void __thiscall ofxFlea3::getNewFrame(unsigned char *)" (?getNewFrame@ofxFlea3@@MAEXPAE@Z)
1>ofxFlea3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual unsigned char * __thiscall FlyCapture2::Image::GetData(void)" (__imp_?GetData@Image@FlyCapture2@@UAEPAEXZ) referenced in function "protected: virtual void __thiscall ofxFlea3::getNewFrame(unsigned char *)" (?getNewFrame@ofxFlea3@@MAEXPAE@Z)
1>ofxFlea3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual unsigned int __thiscall FlyCapture2::Image::GetDataSize(void)const " (__imp_?GetDataSize@Image@FlyCapture2@@UBEIXZ) referenced in function "protected: virtual void __thiscall ofxFlea3::getNewFrame(unsigned char *)" (?getNewFrame@ofxFlea3@@MAEXPAE@Z)
1>ofxFlea3.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void __thiscall FlyCapture2::Image::GetDimensions(unsigned int *,unsigned int *,unsigned int *,enum FlyCapture2::PixelFormat *,enum FlyCapture2::BayerTileFormat *)const " (__imp_?GetDimensions@Image@FlyCapture2@@UBEXPAI00PAW4PixelFormat@2@PAW4BayerTileFormat@2@@Z) referenced in function "protected: virtual void __thiscall ofxFlea3::getNewFrame(unsigned char *)" (?getNewFrame@ofxFlea3@@MAEXPAE@Z)
```

Comment: You are doing something seriously wrong, like #including the library's .h file inside a C++ class.  Not giving the project name nor showing linker errors doesn't help us help you.

Comment: @HansPassant, 10-4, I added project link and linker errors.

Answer (score 0):

By default Visual Studio will use __thiscall for member functions. Since it compiles correctly, it seems like the headers in your library do not explicitly declare the calling convention.

It sounds like you need to use C linkage against the library. Try wrapping the library headers with

```
extern "C" { }
```

Comment: Doing that gives a compiler errors such as this: warning C4190: 'ForceIPAddressToCamera' has C-linkage specified, but returns UDT 'FlyCapture2::Error' which is incompatible with C

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was linking against the 64-bit version of the external FlyCapture2 library. Switching to the 32-bit version solved the problem.